# Am I Handling State Updates in this React Hooks Reducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immutability, react-hooks

In the following code snippet, I have a working reducer that I believe is incorrect in that is re-using existing state and not replacing it. It does work though with no error which concerns me.

1. Is it correct to not need the Object.assign?
2. Should there be an error assuming it's not correct?
3. Any tools that would help me verify correctness for state updates?

The state that is coming into this reducer is just a simple array with just first level objects.  That is, something like:

```
const stateIn = [{id: 101,favorite: 0},{id: 102,favorite: 1},...]
```

And the reducer I'm suspicious of is below:

```
  const speakersReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "loadspeakers": {
        return action.data;
      }
      case "favorite": {
        return state.map((item, index) => {
          if (item.id === action.sessionId) {
            // let speakerToUpdate = Object.assign(item);
            // speakerToUpdate.favorite = 1;
            item.favorite = 1;
            return item;
            // return speakerToUpdate;
          }
          return item;
        });
      }
      ...
      default:
        return state;
    }
  };
  export default speakersReducer;
```

Comment: It works because the result of `map` is a new array, but you are right in that you shouldn't mutate the objects in the array. Returning `{ ...item, favorite: item.favorite + 1 }` from the if statement is the way to go.

Comment: Makes sense @Tholle  are there tools out there that would warn me when I make a mistake like this? I remember there was something in middleware pre-hooks I had used but don't remember details.

Comment: I'm not sure. There are some Eslint rules that can help [against mutating state directly](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-direct-mutation-state.md), but I don't know of any that warn against mutations in a reducer. It might be that TypeScript is smart enough to give you a compile time error for it, but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this correct?

The mutation of `item` is inside the `"favorite"` case is, indeed, suspicious, as @Tholle pointed out.  Mutation in reducers is generally considered an anti-pattern and can frequently lead to bugs.  I would definitely recommend changing it to a immutable pattern.

But then...

> Why doesn't this cause an error, assuming it's not correct?

Mutability in reducers is a common source of errors, but whether a particular bit of mutation causes an error depends on how its mutated and how the reducer is used.

While the favorites case may incorrectly reuse `item` objects from one version of the state to another, it always produces a new state array, since `Array.prototype.map` always returns a new array.  So, for example, the `useReducer` which only cares about the identity of the outer state object will correctly trigger a re-render, despite the mutation.

On the other hand, a redux selector memoized on a specific item in the array would incorrectly return old values.  And if old `items` are cached and reused, the mutation could cause unexpected bugs there as well.  But those are fairly specific cases, so in most cases, I suspect this would work. (I would still change it to not mutate, though)

> Any tools that would help me verify correctness for state updates?

What you want is some form of immutability: there's a number of libraries for immutability in JS.

- [ImmutableJS](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js) defines its own data structures with its own APIs
- [seamless-immutable](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) defines immutable data structures that look like the normal mutable ones
- [immer](https://github.com/mweststrate/immer) lets you do immutable operations with normal mutable operation syntax.

Also Typescript can be used either alone, or in combination with these libraries: allowing objects and arrays to be declared as readonly, and raising compiler errors if you mutate them.

A linter rule might help, too, but it would be tricky unless you're okay with forbidding all mutation in the entire codebase, or else manually toggling the rule on inside reducers.